# How to check if some field does not exist in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have jQuery code like

```
      for(var j in indivudvalbookdetails) {
         if(indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'] == "") {
          ... 
         }
     }
```

Now there might be some items in the loop where status field won't exists, if there are such items the code in the if condition should work.

Comment: Instead of the empty character, check for `undefined`, and use strict comparison operator.

Comment: can u show me in the code

Comment: This is pure javascript, theres no jquery involved here.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if its undefined:

if(typeof indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'] === "undefined") {
          ...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var myElement =  indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'];
if (typeof(myElement) != 'undefined' && myElement != null)
{
  // exists.
}
```

You can also try with *JQuery* like:

```
if ($('#elementId').length > 0) {
  // exists.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is comparing your variable to an empty string. But if this variable is not defined, it can’t compare it, so you can do :

```
if(indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'] == undefined)
```

If the « status » var is defined but just empty you can do

```
 if(indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'] == null)
```

Comment: Non-existing/assigned values are returned as `undefined`. Strict comparison is needed, if the data contains zeros or empty characters.

Comment: tldr: in most cases use `===`. This is one.

Answer (score 1):

You check like this

```
if(!indivudvalbookdetails[j]['status'])
```

Comment: Note that `{status:""}` wont pass the test

Comment: Sorry, didn't think of that. We would have to check for undefined and null as well